# How to sort rows by ON, OFF, SOLD

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have followings 3 values that could be in a row in database - **ON**, **OFF**, **SOLD** (column **sort_it**). When I set the sort clausule on **ORDER BY sort_it ASC**, so I will get the items with a value in the sort_in column **OF**, then **ON** and **SOLD**.
But I need the sequence **ON**, **OFF**, **SOLD**.

Exist any way to do it somehow? I mean... edit a way saving data into database will be demanding, so I would do this in the last moment.

Comment: Hopefully these are enums, not strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can use custom data sortings like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY FIELD(`sort_it`,'ON','OFF','SOLD'),`sort_it`
```

Comment: That should be `,'ON','OFF','SOLD'`. Otherwise +1.

Comment: Corrected order as per mellamokb

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `CASE` statement to generate your custom ordering sequence from the underlying values, something like this:

```
ORDER BY
    CASE sort_it
        WHEN 'ON'   then 1
        WHEN 'OFF'  then 2
        WHEN 'SOLD' then 3
    END
```

Sample Demo: http://sqlize.com/MGz6lLb0Qk

Answer (score 1):

Using Strings is generally a bad idea. it would be better to use a numeric type. Then you can say ON=1, OFF=2 and SOLD=3 and then sort.

Comment: or use the Type: ENUM, which (in the background) is a numberic value, but you can work with the string labels as well: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT t.*, IF(sort_it='ON',1,IF(sort_it='OFF',2,3)) as new_sort FROM Table AS t ORDER by new_sort ASC
```

Another solution from comments on MySql manual:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html

```
select * from tablename order by priority='High' DESC, priority='Medium' DESC, priority='Low" DESC;
```

Comment: @Marcus: I merged the two of my answers.

Comment: Your first solution needs `,` instead of `;` separator in each `IF` statement: http://sqlize.com/2vJ5f5t5pR