# Select Statement By ORDER

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column which holds status of applications - (New/Approved/Declined/Pending)
The column name is status. Now how do I order the select statement to order status so that 'New' applications come to the top of the display.

I tried this `(SELECT * FROM applications ORDER BY status where status ='New')`

This does not work, it is giving me error message.

Comment: `SELECT ... WHERE ... ORDER` is the general syntax. But ordering by status "new", when you're only retrieving "new" rows is kinda pointless.

Comment: What are other values in that column? Just 'Old'?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064459/how-to-sort-rows-by-on-off-sold/8064517#8064517

Comment: Did you try running that query, Oyeme? I didn't get the desired results from your sample. SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY FIELD(`sort_it`,'ON','OFF','SOLD'),`sort_it`; I think `sort_it` has to come before FIELD()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given status values "archived", "new" and "old" (for which neither `ASC` or `DESC` are working) and you want to retrieve all rows, "new" ones first, use this:

```
SELECT * FROM `applications`
ORDER BY IF(`status` = "new", 0, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for this code, worked like magic :-) I appreciate you help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM applications ORDER BY status ASC;
```

If all you have is 'New' and 'Old', then this will result in 'New' first.

If you ONLY want New orders then you don't need an ORDER BY:

```
SELECT * FROM applications WHERE `status` = 'New';
```

If there are all kinds of values, like New/Approved/Declined/Pending and you just want to make sure 'New' is at the top you can do this

```
   SELECT * FROM applications ORDER BY `status`, FIELD(`status`,'New');
```

What if you want 'New' first, then 'Approved', then you don't care what?

```
   SELECT * FROM applications ORDER BY `status`, FIELD(`status`,'New','Approved');
```

(ASC and DESC have no effect after FIELD, but DESC after `status` will put your favorite values at the bottom rather than the top)

What about reversing their order but keeping them at the top? Either change their order in the FIELD() function or see below.

Finally, contrary to the previous suggestion, this does not really work:

```
SELECT * FROM applications ORDER BY FIELD(`status`,'New','Approved'),`status`;
```

To fix it, you need DESC after FIELD, but it gives you your values ordered in **reverse** (i.e. 'Approved' first, then 'New', then the rest):

```
SELECT * FROM applications ORDER BY FIELD(`status`,'New','Approved') DESC,`status`;
```

I think I spent too much time on this answer. Hmmm.

Answer (score 1):

ugly but

```
(SELECT * FROM applications where status ='New')
union all
(SELECT * FROM applications where status !='New')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use this for something serious, replace the status column with a foreign key and add another table for the textual representations of your status_ids.
Then you can sort using

```
SELECT * FROM applications ORDER BY status_id
```

Try to avoid using reserved names for columns. It is possible to use them (with backticks), but can easily lead to problems if you don't take care.